# Why does my open menuIItem dialog box open the save file dialog box?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, rtf

I made a small text editor that saves text from a `RichTextBox` into an `.rtf` file, but whenever I click the open menu option it opens the savefile dialog box. I cannot figure out why can anyone help me out?

Here are the names for the menu dialog items.

MenuStrip:     `menuStrip1`
Save:     `saveMenu`
Open:     `openMenu`
RichTextBox:  `richTextBox1`

here is the code that I am working on below...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //save the file

        private void menuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
        {

            // Text from the rich textbox rtfMain
            string str = richTextBox1.Text;
            // Create a new SaveFileDialog object
            using (SaveFileDialog dlgSave = new SaveFileDialog())
                try
                {
                    // Available file extensions
                    dlgSave.Filter = "Rich Text Format (.rtf)|*.rtf";
                    // SaveFileDialog title
                    dlgSave.Title = "Save";
                    // Show SaveFileDialog
                    if (dlgSave.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && dlgSave.FileName.Length > 0)
                    {
                        richTextBox1.SaveFile(dlgSave.FileName);

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception errorMsg)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(errorMsg.Message);
                } 


        }

        private void openMenu_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)

        {
            using (var of = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                of.DefaultExt = "*.rtf";
                of.Filter = "RTF Files|*.rtf";

                if (of.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    richTextBox1.Rtf = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(of.FileName);
            }



        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the open file menu item is calling the correct event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your openMenu is a child item on the menuStrip1; thus when you click it, the the menuStrip1_ItemClicked event is raised, and that's exactly where you have your code to open a Save dialog.

You should probably get rid of the openMenu_ItemClicked method, and instead have a single menuStrip1_ItemClicked method wired up the menuStrip1's ItemClicked event, and in that method you can determine what item was clicked and what to do accordingly.

So in your menuStrip1_ItemClicked method, you could do something like...

```
if(e.ClickedItem == this.openMenu)
{
    //Code to bring up Open File Dialog here
}
else if (e.ClickedItem == this.saveMenu)
{
    //Code to bring up Save Dialog here
}
```

P.S. you can debug to see the flow of execution, and you'll probably see that the menuStrip1 ItemClicked event is being raised first, and that code being executed first.